# spring partitioning is not performing as expected

Tags: spring-batch

We have a jetty server that is having 6 threads in a task executor that is outperforming 1 master and 4 slaves (2 local and 2 remote) that is having a partition grid size of 4. So if we have a 10k file even with 4 partitions it's not dropping down the time to perform by 4. Assuming some overhead for remote partition still, we are surprised by how slow it is. Has anyone done benchmarking of the remote partition to validate that the overhead of partitioning is not the culprit behind the slow performance? Any pointers as to our slow performance?

Comment: could you please share your config?

Comment: All the relevant configuration is available in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50826773/remote-partition-slave-getting-greedy